# How do you handle deploying rails applications with submodules?

Tags: git, plugins, capistrano, deployment, git-submodules

I recently turned a couple of my plugins into submodules and realized that when you "git clone" a repository, the submodule directory will be empty.  This makes sense for co-developers to initialize their submodules and update.

However, when I deploy with capistrano the submodule code will obviously not be deployed which causes problems.  I could go into the release branch and init and update the module there, but that is obviously not an ideal solution.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to handle this?  Is it as simple as a capistrano task?

I am a bit of a noob on the production side of things.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this recent thread](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=30122), capistrano should be able to init and update your submodules:

```
set :git_enable_submodules,1
```

in config/deploy.rb should be enough, if your `.gitmodules` entries are up to date.
You may need [to patch Capistrano (`lib/capistano/recipes/deploy/scm/git.rb`)](http://blog.nanorails.com/articles/2008/2/18/git-submodules-and-capistrano) to make sure your submodules get included though.

```
    def checkout(revision, destination)
      git      = command

      branch   = head

      fail "No branch specified, use for example 'set :branch, \"origin/master\"' in your deploy.rb" unless branch

      if depth = configuration[:git_shallow_clone]
        execute  = "#{git} clone --depth #{depth} #{configuration[:repository]} #{destination} && " 
      else
        execute  = "#{git} clone #{configuration[:repository]} #{destination} && " 
      end

      execute += "cd #{destination} && #{git} checkout -b deploy #{branch}" 

      if submodules = configuration[:git_enable_submodules]
        execute += " && git-submodule init &&" 
        execute += "git-submodule update" 
      end

      execute
    end
```

---

If you have **[nested submodules](http://speakmy.name/2008/10/capistrano-and-nested-submodules-in-git/)**, you need:

```
gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
$ sudo gem install morhekil-capistrano-deepmodules
```

Just require it at your deployment config:

require 'capistrano/deepmodules'

> The gem will take care of all the rest automatically.
>   You can delete `:git_enable_submodules` from your config, the gem pays no attention to it - if you’re requiring it you’re already saying that you want to enable submodules.
>
> And one more detail to pay attention to - at the moment only remote cache strategy is supported by the gem. It means that you MUST add to your `config` the following line:

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

> It enables the remote cache and it’s really the thing you want to do anyway - deploying large codebases with a lot of submodules and other stuff is really a troublesome experience if you have no server-side cache of it.

Answer (score 5):

`set :git_enable_submodules, 1` on it's own didn't work without this option:

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache`
```

This didn't appear to be documented anywhere and took me a while to figure out. It's generally good to have that option anyway, even without submodules.

Answer (score 5):

With [this commit](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/1ffcb85a6f5d393e2e3c2c7741ee46c412bae143), Capistrano has support for both Git submodules and the --recursive option baked in. To enable Git submodules support, add this to your `deploy.rb` file:

`set :git_enable_submodules, true`

And if you use [recursive Git submodules](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html), add this as well:

`set :git_submodules_recursive, true`