# github project with submodules cloning capistrano

Tags: git, github, capistrano

i am trying to build a capistrano deplyoment script for a git project which has a submodule.

I am running these commands

```
run "git clone git@github.com:GITPROJECT /var/www/myfolder"
```

when i run this the submodule wont clone to /var/www/myfolder instead it only creates an empty folder with the name of the submodule

when I try to run this it wont work either

```
run "cd /var/www/myfolder/submodule && git pull master"
```

can someone help me with this please ?

Comment: i have a work for for this, to run a RM -rf for /var/www/myfolder/submodule and clone the submodule in to that folder again, i dont mind what happens to git as I only need to copy this code to the web root. still thats not a good solution

Comment: This no longer works in Capistrano 3.x

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically what you need is

```
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
```

option in your `deploy.rb` script. It tells capistrano to init and update git submodules after fetching source from the main repo. If for some reason you want to do it manually you can run that from the root directory of your project:

```
git submodule update --init
```

though, if I remember correctly, `--init` is not available in some older versions of git so if it doesn't work you can do it like that:

```
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954213/357743) for more extensive explanation about git options for capistrano.

Comment: great! thanks I missed the git submodule update --init and the git submodule init && git submodule update